# select same multiple record with same id

Tags: sql

My data table looks like this:

```
CustID  CustName     OrderNumber ...
001     John Smith   1234
002     kelly smith  1235
002     kelly smith  4512
```

I would like my record set return something like this:

```
CustID  CustName     OrderNumber ...
001     John Smith   1234
002     kelly smith  1235, 4512
```

If a cust has more than 1 order, return the order# as commas separated value...

Comment: Please explain the logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function listagg()

```
select custid,custname,
    (select listagg(t.ordernumber, ', ') within group (order by 
    t.ordernumber) from table t where t.custid = table.custid and 
    t.custname = table.custname) as ordernumber
from table
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got the logic, let me try to make the syntax works for my database.